# Looking for synonyms for "confirmed by reality"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I would like say that something (like facts) is "confirmed by reality" but with a different word instead of "confirmed"
I thought of the following but I expect they're not precisely accurate:

- endorsed by reality?
- supported by reality?
- sustained by reality?

Are any of these accurate or do you have other suggestions?

From a quick search, it looks like "supported by reality" has more results in Google , but some of them are due to an IT/SQL product named "Reality".

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me. The problem isn't any of the particular synonyms of "confirmed", but the idea of facts being supported by reality. Facts, if the word is being used correctly, ARE reality, they aren't supported by it. Even leaving aside the words "facts", Ideas, hypotheses, guesses and such can be supported by evidence, statistics and opinions, but not by reality.

Comment: It's not all that clear what the context is, but ideas can be verified by **experience**.

Comment: Your verb choices seem okay, but it really depends on the noun.  It wouldn't be accurate to say "Facts are endorsed by reality".  Watch for subject verb agreement.  It would be "Facts are" not "Fact is".

Comment: "These facts are confirmed by reality" I have heard before in life.  Endorsed doesn't quite sound right, but sustained or supported could work.  Keep in mind that this statement is self evident - of course facts are supported by reality, unless your facts are not facts.  Stating this brings your assertions a bit into question.

Comment: Thank you all. "Facts" was just an example that I thought would make things clearer, but apparently a poorly chosen example. Indeed in the final text it's more something like "hypotheses" or "guesses"

Comment: What's wrong with **confirmed**? Why do you need a different word? Why don't any of the alternatives you've already found work?

Comment: @JasonBassford : I was just looking for another word than confirmed because I used it shortly before on another line, I could reuse it but I try to avoid repetition. The other words, according to my own understanding are all fine, but I wanted to be sure if I wasn't misusing them as I'm not 100% sure. I now think that "supported" is correct, but using "endorsed" would be tweaking its meaning a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest and most common synonymous phrase is ***supported*** *by reality*.

---

From comments under the question, the desire to come up with a synonym for *confirm* is based on not wanting to repeat *confirm* after having used it in a previous sentence.

When you say that something is *confirmed by reality*, you are saying that you have a statement about something and that reality is demonstrating it to be true. in short, reality strengthens your claim.

When using [*confirm*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confirm) here, it is in the following sense:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   2 : to make firm or firmer : STRENGTHEN
>       // *confirm* one's resolve

---

As such, I would say that the word with the closest synonymous sense is [**support**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verify):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2 c**: to provide with substantiation : CORROBORATE
>        // *support* an alibi

---

I checked this by looking at Google Ngram Viewer. I entered several search terms, and it [ranked them](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confirmed%20by%20reality%2Cstrengthened%20by%20reality%2Cverified%20by%20reality%2Cendorsed%20by%20reality%2Csupported%20by%20reality%2Csustained%20by%20reality%2Ccorroborated%20by%20reality&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfirmed%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverified%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csupported%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csustained%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorroborated%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconfirmed%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverified%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csupported%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csustained%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorroborated%20by%20reality%3B%2Cc0) in descending order of commonality when used in print:

1. *supported by reality*
2. *confirmed by reality*
3. *sustained by reality*
4. *corroborated by reality*
5. *verified by reality*
6. *substantiated by reality*
7. *strengthened by reality*
8. *endorsed by reality*

[image: confirmed by reality, supported by reality, and variations]

In fact, *supported by reality* is more common than *confirmed by reality*.